# Does Mass Effect 3 have any mod support/User Submitted Content?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I am a huge Bethesda junkie, and mod support for games like Fallout 3, New Vegas, Skyrim is just fantastic.  Easily gives the vanilla games additional YEARS of replayability and enjoyment.

Does EA/Bioware provide mod support, or have they publicly mentioned user-submitted content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SDK in the future for Mass Effect 3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53937/sdk-in-the-future-for-mass-effect-3)

Comment: EA. Lettings people get more than what they paid for. Never going to happen.

Comment: Yep, I asked this question and got shot down hard for future speculation yada yada...

Comment: Is it considered speculative if the answer has the possibility to change?

Comment: I think this question is different than Steve the Maker's question that was posted by Sterno.  This asks if there is *currently* mod support, which has a definitive answer (which is no).  It's not speculative if the answer may change (see all the Minecraft alpha/beta questions) - it's speculative if it can't be answered.  This can be answered, asking about a potential future SDK cannot be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bioware/EA traditionally have no official modding API for the Mass Effect games, but the community still seems to come through.  [This article](http://www.dsogaming.com/news/incoming-mass-effect-3-enbseries-mod-new-screenshots-from-the-latest-enbseries-mod-of-skyrim/) indicates that Boris Vorontsov, author of the ENBSeries mods, will be creating one for Mass Effect 3.

Comment: Vorontsov seems to have abandoned work on ME3.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz That's a bummer :(

Answer (score 0):

EA does not do that, so short answer is NO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Mass Effect 3 is moddable. Here is [a tutorial](http://magicalsilence.sethioz.com/blog/mass-effect-3-mods/) I made if some people are interested. It should give you enough knowledge to get going, and you can always explore more than what I have said in tutorial.